# When I run pnpm install in my monorepo, I don't see the dependencies in the node_modules at the workspace level. Why?

Tags: node-modules, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

I have a monorpo using pnpm workspaces. In my mono repo I have 2 projects/workspaces, each of them with its own package.json.

When runnign pnpm install at teh root level, I get all dependencies added to the root node_modules but not to the workspace node_module.

Why is that?

I tried:

- pnpm add  --filer  (root level)
- pnpm -W add  (root level)

Comment: Can you run `pnpm config list`?